# What does "unless it isn't" mean?

Tags: meaning

The following is a quote from the New York Times. What does the last sentence "Unless it isn't" mean? How can you paraphrase it?

"On the emotional fulcrum of New York City apartment-hunting, size and setting are forever in sway. Does a park view trump a guest bedroom? Is a vast kitchen worth settling blocks from a trendy thoroughfare? Usually, a compromise is struck. Unless it isn't."

Comment: More context is needed, but it's likely saying that compromise is unnecessary if you have enough money.  "Unless it isn't" is a relatively standard ironic idiom.

Answer (score 1):

"isn't" = "is not" - but presumably you knew that?  It means "Usually, a compromise is struck, unless they can't reach a compromise"

Answer (score 1):

Literally, it can be put into a single sentence like the following: *Usually a compromise is struck, unless it is not [struck]*.

The fact that they put it into a sentence of its own is a bit of a childish technique that mature writers sometimes put to use for dramatic effect - essentially dragging the reader's interest into rest of the article to find out what this stark counterexample to their initial statement is. It's sort of like stating a big, nuanced thesis and then completely contradicting it in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

It can be re-phrased in a simple sentence as below

As long as a compromise is NOT struck, A park view trumps a guest bedroom and a vast kitchen is worth settling blocks from a trendy thoroughfare.

Comment: +1 for your **original answer**, because I think it came closest to another possible interpretation (i.e., “Unless it isn’t.” = “Unless a vast kitchen isn’t worth settling blocks from a trendy thoroughfare.”).  (However, your recent edit to add “park view trumps a guest bedroom” doesn’t jive with that interpretation, ‘cause that would require “Unless it **doesn’t**”, so I’m now not so sure exactly what you’re saying, but +1 anyway for noting that there is at least one other interpretation than the “obvious” one mentioned in the other answers.)

Comment: The two phrases are:

_Usually, a compromise is struck. Unless it isn't._